# Após .load em uma div, js não funciona mais

Tags: javascript, html

Quando eu vou pra alguma página do site e tento executar o script funcional, ele só funciona quando eu dou f5, ou seja, ele não funciona com o .load em uma div.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var content = $('#content');
        $('a').live('click', function( e ){
            e.preventDefault();

            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
            }, 300);

            content.html( '<div class="loading"></div>' );
            var href = $( this ).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                success: function( response ){
                    var response = $( '<div>'+response+'</div>' );
                    var data = response.find('#content').html();
                    window.setTimeout( function(){
                        content.fadeOut('slow', function(){
                            content.html(data).fadeIn();
                            var title = response.find('title').text();
                            window.history.pushState( href, title, href );
                            document.title = title;
                        });
                    }, 500 );
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

**PARTE DO HTML**

```
//head, meta, links do js e css
    <body>
    //conteudo
    <div id="content">
    //conteudo carregado
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Você está fazendo `$("#content")` e tem `<div class="content">`. Não seria `$(".content")` ou então `<div id="content">`

Comment: Isso, vou editar, esta certo no meu arquivo, só aqui que não percebi isso

Comment: Os links estão dentro de `#content`?

Comment: Sim, os que estão fora, o load não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você altera o conteúdo da div com `content.html(...)` você está removendo os elementos que possuíam o vínculo com sua rotina através do evento `click`.

Há duas formas simples de solucionar este problema:

- Colocar sua rotina em uma função separada e vincular novamente o evento com `content.on("click", suaRotina)`;
- Adicionar o evento à um elemento que não é substituído, como o próprio `#content` ou então o `body`, ficando assim `content.on("click", "a", function() { ... })`. Desta forma, quando é clicado em um elemento `a`, o evento é passado para seus elementos "pais" até chegar ao `#content` que está escutando o evento. [Mais detalhes](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, deu certo!! :D